# Starting google appengine devserver on all network interfaces

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am currently starting appengine devserver using following maven command

`mvn appengine:devserver`

It starts the devserver on `localhost`. But I need devserver to listen on my wireless interface too, so that `google endpoints` service running on devserver can be accessed from my android device.

Following page describes that command line argument `--address=0.0.0.0` would make devserver listen on all network interfaces. But I have no idea how I can give this argument through maven.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver?hl=en

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#specifying_a_port_for_local_testing

Comment: @SimonKraemer That worked! Thanks. Post this as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is described here [Specifying a local port for local testing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#specifying_a_port_for_local_testing)